# Get 2nd latest custom post type

Tags: custom-post-type, wordpress

I wonder if it's possible in WordPress to not get the absolute latest post from a custom post type but the 2nd or 3rd latest one. Like any additional code for this one:

```
<?php 
$latest = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'car',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    )
);
if($latest->have_posts()){
    $modified_date = $latest->posts[0]->post_modified;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an offset to skip over the first post.

Example:

```
$second_latest = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type'      => 'car',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby'        => 'modified',
    'order'          => 'DESC', // in OP you're using ASC which will get earliest not latest.
    'offset'         => 1,      // skip over the first post.
    'no_found_rows'  => true,   // optimize query since no pagination .needed.
) );
```

Offset details can be found under the pagination section of the WP_Query doc: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters